# Python-Eve. Declare an array of Object IDs on Cerberus schema

Tags: mongodb, eve, cerberus

I am developing an API with Python-Eve and I need to create a MongoDB schema declaration using Cerberus to express a document like the one below:

```
{
    name : 'John Smith',
    type: 'home',
    devices : [
        ObjectID('1234'),
        ObjectID('ABCD'),
        ObjectID('D2AF'),
    ],
}
```

I would like to know how can I declare a Cerberus schema to have an array of `ObjectID`, as is the `devices` key above.

I would like to have a schema for an array of references to other documents, and maybe make them embeddable, as is the single element schema example below, taken from Python-Eve [documentation](http://python-eve.org/features.html#embedded-resource-serialization):

```
{
     'author': {
         'type': 'objectid',
         'data_relation': {
             'resource': 'users',
             'field': '_id',
             'embeddable': True
         },
     },        
 }
```

I suspect this will need a custom type, but I still haven't figured how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, found how to express the devices:

```
{   
    'devices': {
        'type': 'list',
        'schema': {
            'type': 'objectid',
            'data_relation': {
                'resource': 'devices',
                'field': '_id',
                'embeddable': True
            },
        }
    }
}
```

The excellent Cerberus [documentation](http://cerberus.readthedocs.org/en/stable/usage.html#schema-list) has it.